# Creating Pivot Table with Dynamic Range

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Creating a macro that can open multiple files and add a pivot table to each. The files are all formatted the same with the worksheet "details" containing the data needed for the pivot table. However each file has a different amount of rows so I'm trying to use a dynamic range to capture all data on each file.

The coding above this opens the file and formats it as needed to work with the pivot table.

```
         'Set Dynamic Range

  Dim startCell As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim WS As String

    WS = "Details"
    Worksheets(WS).Activate

        'Find Last row and column

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Cells(1, 7).Column).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

     Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select

   Range(Range("G1"), Range("G1").End(xlDown)).Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

          Selection.Name = "DynamicRange"

                     Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

        ' Create Pivot Table

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "DynamicRange", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "Sheet1!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
```

When I get to the "create pivot table" section the first line gives me a run-time error code 1004.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using `Select` and `Activate` as much as possible.  I have modified your code below.  You may want to reexamine the range values.  You need to define the `PivotCache` and the `PivotTable` prior to creating.

```
Dim startCell As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim PvtCache As PivotCache
Dim PvtTab As PivotTable

Set ws = Sheets("Details")

'Find Last row and column

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 7), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Name = "DynamicRange"
Set ws2 = Sheets.Add(After:=ws)
ws2.Name = "PvtTable"

' Create Pivot Table

Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Range("DynamicRange"))

Set PvtTab = PvtCache.CreatePivotTable(ws2.Cells(1, 1), "MyTable")
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help!